# Telneting to Solaris11 on VirtualBox from host computer

Tags: unix, virtualbox, solaris, telnet

**What I want to do ?**

is to telnet to Solaris 11 server installed on VirtualBox from host computer and others using same network.

**Problem ?**

**I can't connect to the virtual solaris 11 telnet via putty or tera term.**

It throws me connection timeout.

```
**** Tera term connection setup ****
Host : 10.0.2.15
Port : 23
Service : Telnet
SSH version : SSH2
Protocol : UNSPEC


**** Putty connection setup ****
Host : 10.0.2.15
Port : 23
Connection type: Telnet
```

---

**`Related Information`**

I set up Solaris 11 on VM VirtualBox ( 4.3.18 ) in Windows 8.1 pro O/S and I had telnet setup through terminal,

```
sudo pkg install /service/network/telnet
.
.
( after the installation was completed )
svcadm enable telnet
```

This made telnet configured right, I could see this status message...

```
svcs - a | grep telnet
online        3:09:16     svc:/network/telnet:default
```

It seems okay, and port number 23 is active and listening. This is the port's status.

```
root@solaris:~$ netstat -an | grep LISTEN
127.0.0.1.5999             *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.4999             *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
      *.111                *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
      *.111                *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
      *.23                 *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
      *.22                 *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.631              *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.62126            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.25               *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.587              *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.36514            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
      *.34657              *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.62132            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.45497            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.35337            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.51040            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.47604            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.50925            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.38960            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.41803            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.38624            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.37266            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.47491            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.59097            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.46758            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.35703            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.57959            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.58703            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
127.0.0.1.54041            *.*                  0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
::1.5999                                *.*                               0      0  128000      0 LISTEN      
      *.111                             *.*                               0      0  128000      0 LISTEN      
      *.23                              *.*                               0      0  128000      0 LISTEN      
      *.22                              *.*                               0      0  128000      0 LISTEN      
::1.631                                 *.*                               0      0  128000      0 LISTEN      
::1.25                                  *.*                               0      0  128000      0 LISTEN      
      *.54242                           *.*                               0      0  128000      0 LISTEN
```

And network information of Solaris 11 on VirtualBox is...

```
DHCP Address : 10.0.2.15
Subnet Mask : 255.255.255.0
Default Route : [            ] ( blank )

root@solaris:~$ netstat -rn

Routing Table: IPv4
  Destination           Gateway           Flags  Ref     Use     Interface 
-------------------- -------------------- ----- ----- ---------- --------- 
default              10.0.2.2             UG        3       5147 net0      
10.0.2.0             10.0.2.15            U         3          0 net0      
127.0.0.1            127.0.0.1            UH        2        956 lo0       

Routing Table: IPv6
  Destination/Mask            Gateway                   Flags Ref   Use    If   
--------------------------- --------------------------- ----- --- ------- ----- 
::1                         ::1                         UH      2       0 lo0   
fe80::/10                   fe80::a00:27ff:fe09:faf3    U       2       0 net0
```

Network seems fine, I can browse the Internet through the pre-installed FireFox by the way.

VirtualBox network configuration looks like this

```
connected to NAT
Adopter type : Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)
random mode : false
MAC address : 08002709FAF3
Port Forwarding setting : none.
```

My host computer network status is...

```
DHCP enable: true
IPv4 Address: 192.168.1.85
IPv4 Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
IPv4 Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
IPv4 DHCP Server: 192.168.1.1
IPv4 DNS Server: 168.126.63.1, 168.126.63.2
```

Should I give you more info related to telnet configuration?

What seems to be the matter? How can I get through this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access a VM service when using NAT unless you configure a reverse forwarding port.

The simplest workaround is to switch your virtual NIC from NAT to bridge mode in which case your VM will be visible from your LAN.

Comment: Thanks but I have no NIC network option on VirtualBox. NAT, NAT Network, Bridge Adapter, Internal Network, Host-Only Adaptor, Normal Driver are all I got.

Comment: "Bridged adapter" is what you need to use.

Comment: I've just changed the network setting, and the Internet doesn't work in Solaris 11 on VirtualBox. There's no defined DHCP Address, it says.

Comment: Is the VB interface attached to the right interface on your host machine ?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what you mean by VB interface.

Comment: By the way, you are on the wrong site and should ask a moderator for your question to be moved to superuser.com

Comment: You gave me a good hint, portforwarding. Just mapping the host port and guest port in portforwarding config was enough to telnet to the virtual machine. Thanks !